# GridSearch for an estimator inside a OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to perform GridSearchCV in a SVC model, but that uses the one-vs-all strategy. For the latter part, I can just do this:

```
model_to_set = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel="poly"))
```

My problem is with the parameters. Let's say I want to try the following values:

```
parameters = {"C":[1,2,4,8], "kernel":["poly","rbf"],"degree":[1,2,3,4]}
```

In order to perform GridSearchCV, I should do something like:

```
 cv_generator = StratifiedKFold(y, k=10)
 model_tunning = GridSearchCV(model_to_set, param_grid=parameters, score_func=f1_score, n_jobs=1, cv=cv_generator)
```

However, then I execute it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../main.py", line 66, in <module>
    argclass_sys.set_model_parameters(model_name="SVC", verbose=3, file_path=PATH_ROOT_MODELS)
  File "/.../base.py", line 187, in set_model_parameters
    model_tunning.fit(self.feature_encoder.transform(self.train_feats), self.label_encoder.transform(self.train_labels))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 354, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 392, in _fit
    for clf_params in grid for train, test in cv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 473, in __call__
    self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 296, in dispatch
    job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 85, in fit_grid_point
    clf.set_params(**clf_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 241, in set_params
    % (key, self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: Invalid parameter kernel for estimator OneVsRestClassifier
```

Basically, since the SVC is inside a OneVsRestClassifier and that's the estimator I send to the GridSearchCV, the SVC's parameters can't be accessed.

In order to accomplish what I want, I see two solutions:

1. When creating the SVC, somehow tell it not to use the one-vs-one strategy but the one-vs-all.
2. Somehow indicate the GridSearchCV that the parameters correspond to the estimator inside the OneVsRestClassifier.

I'm yet to find a way to do any of the mentioned alternatives. Do you know if there's a way to do any of them? Or maybe you could suggest another way to get to the same result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

When you use nested estimators with grid search you can scope the parameters with `__` as a separator. In this case the SVC model is stored as an attribute named `estimator` inside the `OneVsRestClassifier` model:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

iris = load_iris()

model_to_set = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel="poly"))

parameters = {
    "estimator__C": [1,2,4,8],
    "estimator__kernel": ["poly","rbf"],
    "estimator__degree":[1, 2, 3, 4],
}

model_tunning = GridSearchCV(model_to_set, param_grid=parameters,
                             score_func=f1_score)

model_tunning.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

print model_tunning.best_score_
print model_tunning.best_params_
```

That yields:

```
0.973290762737
{'estimator__kernel': 'poly', 'estimator__C': 1, 'estimator__degree': 2}
```

Comment: Hi ogrisel, is there any need to use OneVsRestClassifer with SVC? Can't SVC handle multiple target values by itself?

Comment: OneVsRestClassifer can be useful for adding multilabel support. SVC just supports multiclass by default.

Also the native multiclass impl. of SVC is based on a OvO scheme that is a bit different.

Comment: @ogrisel is it possible to display the best score for each individual class in case of multi-label classification (i.e., if the X, y are made by make_multilabel_classification)? And what does the best score 0.97 in this example represent for, is it scored by one of the classifiers in the OneVsRestClassifier or it is the average of three classifiers (since there are three classes in the iris dataset)?

Comment: Just to add, if your onevsrest is also part of a pipeline, you just prepend the name given to the onevsrest classifier in the pipeline.

Comment: The accepted code selects the same model parameters for each individual model, which is less than optimal. You should use grid_search to identify the best model for each class that you are trying to predict. Unfortunately, this is not implemented in sklearn and therefore you need to use an ugly loop.

Answer (score 6):

For Python 3, the following code should be used

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

iris = load_iris()

model_to_set = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel="poly"))

parameters = {
    "estimator__C": [1,2,4,8],
    "estimator__kernel": ["poly","rbf"],
    "estimator__degree":[1, 2, 3, 4],
}

model_tunning = GridSearchCV(model_to_set, param_grid=parameters,
                             scoring='f1_weighted')

model_tunning.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

print(model_tunning.best_score_)
print(model_tunning.best_params_)
```

Comment: for those wondering _what did change_, only the way you specify the metric you wanna use when instantiating the GridSearchCV is different

Answer (score 5):

```
param_grid  = {"estimator__alpha": [10**-5, 10**-3, 10**-1, 10**1, 10**2]}

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss='log',penalty='l1'))

model = GridSearchCV(clf,param_grid, scoring = 'f1_micro', cv=2,n_jobs=-1)

model.fit(x_train_multilabel, y_train)
```

Comment: should add some explanation to make a better answer.