# Can RandomizedSearchCV run on multiple CPU?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use RandomizedSearchCV to learn hypeparameters of logistic regression. Here the code:

```
random_searcher = RandomizedSearchCV(
  estimator = MyLogRegClassifier(),
  param_distributions = {'penalty': ['l2', 'l1'], 
                         'class_weight': [None, 'auto'],
                         'C': logspace(-20, 20, 10000), 
                         'intercept_scaling': logspace(-20, 20, 10000)},
  cv = 4,
  scoring = make_scorer(f1_score, average='samples'),
  n_iter = 100,
  n_jobs = -1,
  pre_dispatch = 10,
  refit = False
)
random_searcher.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
```

However, it couldn't use multiple CPU, it runs always on one. But when I switching to `GridSearchCV` it spawns multiple processes and loads all CPUs.

```
grid_searcher = GridSearchCV(
  estimator = MyLogRegClassifier(),
  param_grid = {'penalty': ['l2', 'l1'], 
                'class_weight': [None, 'auto'],
                'C': logspace(-20, 20, 10000), 
                'intercept_scaling': logspace(-20, 20, 10000)},
  cv = 4,
  scoring = make_scorer(f1_score, average='samples'),
  n_jobs = -1,
  pre_dispatch = 10,
  refit = False
)
grid_searcher.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
```

X_tr is sparse matrix with shape (6700, 25640), y_tr is dense matrix with shape (6700, 83)
`MyLogRegClassifier` is essentially `OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())`.

```
class MyLogRegClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, C=1.0, penalty='l2', 
                 intercept_scaling=1, class_weight=None, n_jobs=1):
        self.C = C
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs
        self.penalty = penalty
        self.intercept_scaling = intercept_scaling
        self.class_weight = class_weight

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(
            C=self.C, penalty=self.penalty,
            intercept_scaling=self.intercept_scaling, 
            class_weight=self.class_weight),
                                       n_jobs=self.n_jobs)
        self.clf.fit(X, y)
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.clf.predict(X)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you wrap `LogisticRegression` into `MyLogRegClassifier`? You can use `OneVsRestClassifier` classifier with grid_search directly. All you'll have to do is to change keys of your parameters dict [by prepending](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12637528/1190430) `estimator__` like `estimator__penalty`

Comment: Because if I need to somehow tune my classifier, it is better to change code in one place. However, thanks for the tip.

Comment: This is odd. Can you produce a minimum example? It should definitely work. Which version of sklearn are you on?

Comment: Also don't use logspace for RandomizedSearchCV. Providing a list instead of a continuous distribution basically throws most of the benefits of RandomizedSearchCV out of the window