# How to gridsearch an estimator embeded in OneVsRestClassifier using Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am doing model selection and hyperparameter tuning using GridSearchCV. From initial experiment, it turns out SVC with rdf kernel has the best performance. The problem with that is it is too slow (200K+) sample. Using OneVsRestClassifier can parallelize SVC (n_jobs). However gridsearchcv doesn't work for this embeded estimator when I am using Pipeline to test multiple estimators at the same time.

```
pipe = Pipeline([('clf', SVC())]) # Placeholder Estimator

# Candidate learning algorithms and their hyperparameters
search_space = [{'clf': [OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(tol=0.1, gamma='scale', probability=True), n_jobs=-1],
                 'clf__kernel': ['rbf', 'linear'],
                 'clf__C': [1, 10, 100]},

                {'clf': [LogisticRegression(tol=0.1, penalty='l1', solver='saga', multi_class='multinomial', n_jobs=8)], 
                 'clf__C': [1, 10, 100]},

                {'clf': [RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=8)],
                 'clf__n_estimators': [50, 100, 200, 300, 400],
                 'clf__max_depth': [10, 20, 30],
                 'clf__min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4],
                 'clf__min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10]},

                {'clf': [MultinomialNB()],
                 'clf__alpha': [0.1, 0.5, 1]}]

gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, search_space, cv=skf, scoring='accuracy', verbose=10)
```

I got error

```
Invalid Parameter __kernel
```

But according to [GridSearch for an estimator inside a OneVsRestClassifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632992/gridsearch-for-an-estimator-inside-a-onevsrestclassifier), this method should work. I think it is the Pipeline that messed it up since it basically adds another layer on top of OneVsRestClassifier. How exactly do I perform gridsearchcv for this nested estimator?

Comment: @desertnaut it did seem to load the first estimator after I changed to `clf__estimator__kernel` based on the output. But I got an `ValueError: WRITEBACKIFCOPY base is read-only` immediately.

Comment: Well, no idea about that...!!!??? We would need a [MCVE] to investigate it...

Comment: @desertnaut But this error only occurs after I  added "estimator" to the parameter. It runs fine with just `SVC` without `OneVsRestClassifier`. Actually, the error goes away if I take out `n_jobs=-1` from `OneVsRestClassifier`. But without running it in parallel, it negates the purpose of using `OneVsRestClassifier`

Comment: How many classes & features in your data?

Comment: @desertnaut About 170 different classes. It is a text classification so the data gets converted to sparse matrix. After vectorization, I took the top 2000 features.

Comment: https://github.com/ray-project/tune-sklearn - this package helps speed up the tuning process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, the pipeline looks for a parameter `kernel` in `OneVsRestClassifier`, can't find one (unsurprisingly, since the module does not have such a parameter), and raises an error. Since you actually want the parameter `kernel` (and, subsequently, `C`) of `SVC`, you should go a level deeper: change the first 3 entries of your `search_space` to:

```
{'clf': [OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(tol=0.1, gamma='scale', probability=True), n_jobs=-1],
 'clf__estimator__kernel': ['rbf', 'linear'],
 'clf__estimator__C': [1, 10, 100]}
```

and you should be fine.

Irrespectively of the error, however, your rationale for using this approach:

> The problem with that is it is too slow (200K+) sample. Using OneVsRestClassifier can parallelize SVC (n_jobs).

is not correct. `OneVsRestClassifier` will parallelize the fitting of the `n_classes` different `SVC` estimators, **not** the `SVC` itself. In effect, you are trying to avoid a bottleneck (`SVC`) by wrapping something else around it (here `OneVsRestClassifier`) which imposes its own additional computational complexity, only to (unsurprisingly) find it again in front of you.

We can demonstrate this with some timings on dummy data - let's try a somewhat realistic dataset of 10K samples, 5 features, and 3 classes:

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples = 10000, n_features=5, n_redundant=0, n_informative=5,
                             n_classes = 3, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=42)

%timeit for x in range(10): SVC().fit(X,y)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 7.72 s per loop

%timeit for x in range(10): OneVsRestClassifier(SVC()).fit(X, y)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 21.1 s per loop
```

Well, that's your baseline difference; now setting `n_jobs=-1` helps:

```
%timeit for x in range(10): OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(), n_jobs=-1).fit(X, y)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 19 s per loop
```

but, unsurprisingly, it does so only in relation to the un-parallelized `OneVsRestClassifier`, **not** in relation to `SVC` itself.

The difference is getting worse with more features & classes; without going to your full case, here is the situation with 10 features and 5 classes (same no. of samples, 10K):

```
X1, y1 = make_classification(n_samples = 10000, n_features=10, n_redundant=0, n_informative=10,
                             n_classes = 5, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=42)

%timeit for x in range(10): SVC().fit(X1,y1)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 10.3 s per loop

%timeit for x in range(10): OneVsRestClassifier(SVC()).fit(X1, y1)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 30.7 s per loop

%timeit for x in range(10): OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(), n_jobs=-1).fit(X1, y1)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 24.9 s per loop
```

So, I would seriously suggest to reconsider your approach (and your aims) here.

(All timings in Google Colab).